# Cast string with decimal to int before putting it in JSON over Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to change a value, which is parsed through CGI over GET to Python before I want to send all the values over MQTT with JSON.

The value is as follows:

```
exposure = "0.0"
```

which is gained over CGI like so:

```
if form.getvalue("exposure"):
        req["excompensaton"] = form.getvalue("exposure")
```

Sadly, however, the value needs to be "0", not "0.0" before I can send it over MQTT with JSON.

I've tried:

```
if form.getvalue("exposure"):
        req["excompensaton"] = int(form.getvalue("exposure")
```

Sadly this came up with the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'

I also tried math.floor, but it ended up telling me that it needs to float.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the behavior of `int()` is what you want, cast to a float first:

```
int(float(form.getvalue("exposure")))
```

If you want to be certain of getting one of `math.floor()` or `math.ceil()`, you can incorporate those:

```
int(math.floor(float(form.getvalue("exposure"))))
```